# how to calculate speed in ios 7 using coreLocation framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, ios7, core-location

prior to iOS 7 i used to calculate speed as below

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

      double speed = newLocation.speed;
      NSLog(@"Speed of Device is %f",newLocation.speed); 

      // manual method
      if(oldLocation != nil)
      {
           CLLocationDistance distanceChange = [newLocation getDistanceFrom:oldLocation];
           NSTimeInterval sinceLastUpdate = [newLocation.timestamp 
           timeIntervalSinceDate:oldLocation.timestamp];
           double calculatedSpeed = distanceChange / sinceLastUpdate;

           NSLog(@"Speed of Device is %f",calculatedSpeed); 
     }  
 }
```

since this method is deprecated ,. please suggest me another way to calculate speed using iOS7 using CoreLocation.

Comment: The documentation itself tells you what method to use. From apple docs: Tells the delegate that a new location value is available. (Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Use locationManager:didUpdateLocations: instead.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *loc = locations.lastObject;
    double speed = loc.speed;
    NSLog(@"%f", speed);
}
```

Comment: This always giving -1.

Comment: Did you test on an actual device?

Comment: Yes I tested in real device so I calculated manually like @Durga Prasad Vundavalli 1st Approach.

Answer (score 4):

**1st Approach**:Saving the oldLocation from previous call. .For more accuracy `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`.
This might give you inaccurate result in some scenarios.(like stopped or missed to report one location etc).

```
CLLocationDistance distanceChange = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];
NSTimeInterval sinceLastUpdate = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:oldLocation.timestamp];
double calculatedSpeed = distanceChange / sinceLastUpdate;
NSLog(@"calculatedSpeed using old location:%.1f",calculatedSpeed);
```

**2nd Approach** is to use **speed** property.using this property you will get  the current speed of the vehicle(moving speed).which will give **speed** in **m/s**. To convert it to **km/hr** use

```
location.speed * 3.6
```

use `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = locations.lastObject;
    double speed = location.speed*3.6;
    NSLog(@"%f", speed);
}
```

Comment: This always giving -1.

Comment: @DurgaPrasadVundavalli dear,in first approach did you tell me **calculatedSpeed** actually what will give us  **speed** in **m/s** or **km/hr**.

Comment: @DurgaPrasadVundavalli dear,
2nd approach is always giving me -1.
I try both approach,first one is giving me a positive value but you dont mention that about  **calculatedSpeed** actually what will give us  **speed** in **m/s** or **km/hr**.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The method "getDistanceFrom:" is simply renamed to "distanceFromLocation:" - you can use that.

`CLLocationDistance distanceChange = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];`

Comment: that method is fine .. how can we get those newlocation and fromlocation since locationManager:manager didUpdateToLocation:newLocation
fromLocation:oldLocation is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Other solution in km/h.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
CLLocation *location = [self.locationManager location];

        double speedCalculada = location.speed * 3.6;
        self.lblVelocidad.text = (location.speed<0)?@"-- km/h":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d          Km/h", (int) speedCalculada];
}
```